Type based on passed props
I'm encountering an issue with a React component that accepts two props. Here's how it's set up:
type Props<T> = {
  value: T,
  onChange: (date: T) => void
}

const DateRangeInput: React.FC<Props<DateRange | Date | undefined>> = ({
  // Component code here
})


And here's an example usage of the component:
import { DateRange } from "../Common/DateRangeInputV2";
const Loading = lazy(() => import("../Common/Loading"));

export type DateRange = {
  start: Date | undefined;
  end: Date | undefined;
};

export const InsuranceDetails = () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState<DateRange>({
    start: undefined,
    end: undefined,
  });

  const handleDateChange = (date: DateRange) => {
    console.log("date in insurance", date);
    setDate(date);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <DateRangeInput
        name="range_date"
        value={date}
        onChange={handleDateChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

The error I'm encountering is:
Type '(date: DateRange) => void' is not assignable to type '(date: DateRange | Date | undefined) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'date' and 'date' are incompatible.
    Type 'DateRange | Date | undefined' is not assignable to type 'DateRange'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'DateRange'.ts(2322)
DateRangeInputVivek.tsx(41, 3): The expected type comes from property 'onChange' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props<DateRange | Date | undefined>'
(property) onChange: (date: DateRange | Date | undefined) => void


Playground
As the type of value is of DateRange then same should be accepted by my onChange. Is there any way to handle this, without using any?

The error you're getting doesn't match the code example you posted above it. You're passing a void (seemingly a result of a void function call), instead of the expected Date | DateRange | undefined

@SamuelHulla yes you are right I have changed the code can you please look at it now

Make DateRangeInput generic, e.g. in T extends DateRange | Date | undefined. Then the appropriate onChange argument type can be inferred from the value type via Props<T>.
